# Skyrim Input not working

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

Hey my inputs in skyrim are not working. Let me elaborate on this:
My x and y axis from my mouse are no longer changing my view, and I cannot move around however I CAN open the in game script console (I'm on PC) Is there a way to fix this? Or a common bug no-one has found out how to fix?

Answer (score 1):

It sounds as though you have another input device blocking your inputs.

The first thing you want to check is that you don't have any other input devices plugged in, like a Controller or some other form of gamepad.

If that isn't the case, check to make sure your mouse *is* working properly. Check the connection (usb input is being read properly) or if it's a wireless device, make sure the batteries are fresh.

Comment: Actually, i don't think the connected controller is a problem. Mine is plugged in the entire time, and i can still play skyrim without unplug it.

Comment: @YUNOWORK does your controller support xinput (e.g. is it an xbox controller)? Skyrim doesn't support the majority of controllers at all.

Comment: @MrLemon It is a PS3 controller with the MotionInJoy Driver which can emulate all kind of controllers. So it does, yes.